# "Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit" when using tbl_uvregression from gtsummary

Tags: r, cox-regression, gtsummary

When trying to run `tbl_uvregression` from `gtsummary` with the following code:

```
tbl_uvregression(
  database,
  method=survival::coxph,
  y = Surv(time = survival, event = status),
  exponentiate = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: C stack usage  15927472 is too close to the limit

The database is pretty large (187 observations of 102 variables, a univariate Cox analysis to be performed for each of them) but not as heavy to handle as that!

Here is my c stack info:

```
Cstack_info()
      size    current  direction eval_depth 
  15922790      20424          1          2
```

When the database is split in two (187 observations, 50 variables), I can run `tbl_uvregression` but I can't merge the 2 produced files for the same reason as above. "C stack is too cloose to the limit".

```
tblcox1 <- tbl_uvregression(
  database_part1,
  method=survival::coxph,
  y = Surv(time = survival, event = status),
  exponentiate = TRUE)

tblcox2 <- tbl_uvregression(
  database_part2,
  method=survival::coxph,
  y = Surv(time = survival, event = status),
  exponentiate = TRUE)
```

```
object.size(tblcox1) %>% format(units = "Mb")
[1] "120.9 Mb"
object.size(tblcox2) %>% format(units = "Mb")
[1] "102.9 Mb"
tblcox1_butch <- tbl_butcher(tblcox1)
object.size(tblcox1_butch) %>% format(units = "Mb")
[1] "45.3 Mb"
tblcox2_butch <- tbl_butcher(tblcox2)
object.size(tblcox2_butch) %>% format(units = "Mb")
[1] "38.8 Mb"
tbl_stack(list(tblcox1_butch, tblcox2_butch))
Error: C stack usage  15927472 is too close to the limit
tbl_merge(list(tblcox1_butch, tblcox2_butch))
Error: C stack usage  15927472 is too close to the limit
```

Is there anything I can do to increase my c stack (or another tweak) to run my `tbl_uvregression` properly?

(former discussions did not help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433246/tbl-uvregression-gives-error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735702/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit-in-r))

Comment: I know you are using `gtsummary` but I am not sure it is a `gtsummary` issue but rather a memory allocation one